# Is there a quick way to delete saves off of the steam cloud?

Tags: steam, endless-space, steam-cloud

I've been playing a Endless Space for a while now, and I've got quite a few saves saved up... Any way I can clean house and mass delete the ones I no longer need?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

***Note**: This answer is old (May, 2013), and may be out of date due to changes to the Steam platform. Some users have reported this solution not working. Proceed with caution!*

---

**Unfortunately, there is no native feature allowing this, but it is possible.** (as of 2013/Jan/25) It will take some work, but you can delete from the Steam cloud by following these instructions:

> **HOW TO *DELETE* FILES STORED IN STEAM CLOUD SERVERS**
>
> ### **Context:**
>
> I've read many times on this forum topics with concerns about
> the fact that it's impossible to manage files stored in Steam Cloud
> servers. This can be very annoying if you want to know exactly what
> files are in the Cloud or to solve sync problems such as savegame
> overwriting. Since no good solution was available, I've decided to
> look at the issue and try to understand how Steam Cloud works.
>
> ### **Presentation of Steam Cloud:**
>
> Steam Cloud is used to backup config
> files and savegames online in order to access them from every
> computer. It's a feature that can be enabled/disabled through two
> different dialogs:
>
> - Steam > Settings > Downloads + Cloud > Enable Steam Cloud synchronization for games which support it (will affect all the games)
> - Right-click on a game > Properties > Updates > Enable Steam Cloud synchronization for GameName (will only affect the selected game)
>
> ### **How it works:**
>
> The first thing you should know is that there are most
> of the time three versions of your save files:
>
> - the original version stored in the game folder or in AppData (`S1`)
> - the cloud version stored in Steam\userdata\SteamID\AppID (`S2`)
> - the cloud version stored in Steam servers (`S3`)
>
> When you start a game for the first time, `S1` is created. When you close it, `S1` is copied to `S2` which is then synced to `S3`.
>
> When you start a game from another computer, if Steam has `S3` on its servers but doesn't find `S2` on your computer, it will copy `S3` to `S2`. **Steam Cloud automatically downloads the missing files each time you start Steam.**
>
> You understand that the most important save location for us is `S2`. If we play a bit with it, we should be able to reach our goal. So what's in `S2`? Note: some games don't have `S1` and write directly to `S2`, while others don't use the `S2` remote folder to store the save files. In this case, the remotecache.vdf file in `S2` points directly to the files located in `S1` (thanks TheOdds for the detail).
>
> **Userdata contents:**
>
> In **Steam\userdata** you should have 1 (or more) folder corresponding to your account ID (**SteamID**). Open it and you'll find a folder for each game using Steam Cloud you have installed. The folder name is the **AppID** of the game (found in the URL when you visit its store page, it's a number like 220 for Half-Life 2). In the game folder you'll find:
>
> - a **remote** folder: it contains all the files that are being synced up with Steam servers
> - a **remotecache.vdf** file: the file describe the properties (such as file size or modification date) of the files contained in the remote folder
>
> ### **In this tutorial there are 2 main steps:**
>
> 1. Bringing up the Cloud Sync
>    Conflict dialog
> 2. Deleting the Cloud files
>
> *Note that you have to repeat these steps for EVERY game you want to delete Steam Cloud files!*
>
> But first I would like you to delete your **AppID** folder and restart
> Steam: you'll see that it will automatically recreate the **AppID** folder
> and download the missing files from Steam Cloud. This verification is
> important for you to make sure that the whole operation has been
> successful.
>
> After this long but necessary introduction, let the magic begin!
>
> ## **I. Bringing up the Cloud Sync Conflict dialog**
>
> The first part is probably the most difficult. In order to get rid of
> the files stored in Steam servers, we'll need the help of the Cloud
> Sync Conflict dialog. It appears when the Cloud files differ from the
> local files stored on your computer. There are several ways to get it,
> I'll give you two:
>
> 1. Exit Steam and make sure that Steam Cloud is enabled.
> 2. Alter the content of all files in **Steam\userdata\SteamID\AppID\remote**. The
>    objective is that every file becomes different from the ones stored in
>    the Cloud. You can't simply delete the files otherwise Steam will
>    download them from the Cloud. You can corrupt them by deleting all
>    their content. 0 bytes files will indeed do the trick. To do this
>    (thanks Kevin92 for the tip):
>
> - Hold Shift and right-click on your remote folder.
> - Click on "Open command window here".
> - Enter powershell.
> - Enter clc C:\Steam\userdata\SteamID\AppID\remote* (clc + absolute path of your remote folder + * to affect all the files).
> - Done: all your files are now 0 bytes!
>
>   - **Warning: be sure of the path your enter to not delete accidentally system or user files! There is no confirmation when you press Enter!**
>
> 3. Delete **remotecache.vdf**
>    in **Steam\userdata\SteamID\AppID**.
> 4. Start Steam, start the game and the "[Sync conflict](http://img864.imageshack.us/img864/148/syncconflict.png)" dialog
>    should appear.
>
> **A simpler way but not as efficient:**
>
> 1. Start Steam.
> 2. Disable Steam Cloud.
> 3. Delete all files in **Steam\userdata\SteamID\AppID**.
> 4. Start
>    the game to create fresh (and thus different) new files.
> 5. Exit the
>    game and Steam.
> 6. Delete remotecache.vdf in
>    **Steam\userdata\SteamID\AppID**.
> 7. Start Steam.
> 8. Enable Steam Cloud, start the game
>    and the "Sync conflict" dialog should appear. **Note** that this
>    method may not affect all the files (and you need to modify all of
>    them if you want to delete all of them later).
>
> ## **II. Deleting the Cloud files**
>
> Ok now it's piece of cake. Once the dialog is opened, don't click on
> any option.
>
> 1. Go to **Steam\userdata\SteamID\AppID** and delete ALL the
>    files in it, **remote** folder and **remotecache.vdf**.
> 2. Go back to the
>    Cloud Sync Conflict dialog and click on "Upload to the Steam Cloud".
>    Steam will sync your AppID folder with nothing in it... meaning that
>    all the files on the Cloud will be deleted! You don't believe me? Wait
>    for it, the demonstration is right after
> 3. Then the game should start
>    automatically. But... it will create new files that will be synced
>    when I'll leave the game!! Indeed it will, except if you...
> 4. Alt-tab
>    the game and disable Steam Cloud.
> 5. Return to the game and exit it
>    (or kill it through process manager). No files will be synced up!
> 6. Exit Steam.
> 7. Delete the **AppID** folder.
>
> **Note:** if you haven't modified all the files in step I, only the
> modified ones will be deleted. The others will remain in Steam Cloud.
>
> ### **How to make sure it worked?**
>
> Remember at the beginning when I told you to delete your **AppID** folder
> to see that Steam Cloud automatically download the missing files each
> time you start Steam? Normally, if there is no file left in Steam
> Cloud, it won't download anything on your computer. So here is how to
> check it:
>
> 1. Enable Steam Cloud.
> 2. Exit Steam.
> 3. Delete the AppID
>    folder (if you didn't do it in step II).
> 4. now check `S3` (Cloud files) and compare them with `S2` (local files).
>    Nothing in `S3`? Nothing copied to `S2`!
> 5. Check your
>    **Steam\userdata\SteamID** folder. No new **AppID** folder has been created!
>
> You can eventually check on another computer and see that no files are
> downloaded anymore from Steam Cloud.
>
> Congratulations, you have successfully deleted your files from Steam
> Cloud.

I know you asked for a *quick* way to do it, and probably already found this answer if you did any Googling, but I figured I would repost it here for future users since this appears to be the only answer as of 2013/Jan/25.

---

[This excellent guide](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=28393747&postcount=1) is from user [Homme Crabe](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/member.php?u=657707) on the Steam forums; **full credit to the author!** I am merely copying here so there is a second copy just in case the original is lost/its URL is altered (plus, we can now edit it).

Source: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=28393747&postcount=1

Comment: Ok this method is great im seeing a lot of people have progress with it but when trying to execute the clc command in powershell both as administrator and as a normal user i get the access denied red line error Are there any fixes for that? I tried making the file not read only and it did nothing it stays read only but im sure thats not the issue this is my laptop i have have all admin privelages and have disabled UAC

Comment: @Lukman Perhaps verify that your account/the administrator has ownership of the file along with read/write/delete access. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx

Comment: @Lukman Furthermore, make sure that the file isn't currently in use. The game which uses it should not be running, or perhaps Steam shouldn't be running either. If the file is in use, that will typically lock it from external deletion/modification.

Comment: I would not recommend these steps. The instructions produced a sync conflict dialog as described, but continued to a sync/upload failed error dialog and now my game crashes at start.

Comment: This did not work for me at all (neither approach) this did allow me to create a fresh save game, but not erase old data. http://steamcommunity.com/app/211420/discussions/0/368542844482177045/

Comment: It is possible that these changes are now outdated, as they are over three years old and Steam's cloud services may very well have changed.