# Delete files from steam cloud

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

I want to delete certain files inside Steam cloud save for a certain game

```
Steam\userdata\SteamID\AppID
```

I have no problem to *change* any file. This is as easy as starting game, changing file and then exiting game (replacing game exe-file if game is agreessively overrides files upon exit).

But for a quite some time, when I try to use same method to *delete* any file - it will just reappear, either on exiting game or just before it's started.

Now I've run into a weird problem where for some reasons my save files contains folder which contains underscore `_` in front and this kind of breaks the game: I can't create character with same name. So I would really like to find a solution. Below are my thoughts/attempts.

---

1. How to delete single file from Steam cloud?

I've tried for a few hours to apply solutions found using the google (e.g. [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/102694/135338)): disabling/enabling clouds, deleting files at various moments, deleting/editing `remotecache.vdf` of corresponding game with or w/o Steam running, etc. etc.

The deleted files just reappear.

Yet during my tries I've never seen `Cloud Sync Conflict` Steam dialog and honestly I don't even remember when I saw it last time.

---

2. How to force [Cloud Sync Conflict](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/support/faq/cloud_conflict.JPG) dialog?

I've read that with that dialog I can choose option to take local files as they are, not sure if it will work for *deleted* files, but I'd like to try it.

---

3. How to *directly* browse my Steam cloud saves files (not synced content on my PC)?

In theory there could be third party tool or web-site to manually edit content. Potentially there will be the option to *delete* file.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you're following the directions properly. Have you tried [Steam Cloud File Manager Lite](https://github.com/GMMan/SteamCloudFileManagerLite)? 3 years inactive, but Steam doesn't change core parts often. All pre-releases and may be buggy, but that's always a risk with any third-party software, and there doesn't seem to be any alternatives. As for seeing what exists, they "recently" (~2018, partially because of GDPR) added support to [download your Cloud data](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/339909/203077). There doesn't seem to be any functionality for deleting it though.

Comment: Also note that this doesn't always just work. Some games are also more difficult, e.g. Bethesda games like Fallout NV that end up with tons of saves because of the default settings.